# How can I read a .tar.gz file with PHP?

Tags: php, zip, tar

I am building a system for people to upload .tar (and .tar.gz, .tar.bz2, .zip, etc) files in PHP. Uploading the files is fine, but I would like to list files contained in the archive after it has been uploaded.

Can someone recommend a good PHP library that can read file archives?

I found [File_Archive](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Archive) on Pear but it hasn't been updated in a few years. ZipArchive works great for .zip files, but I need something that can handle more file types.

**update** I'm running on RHEL6, PHP 5.2, and Apache 2.2.

Comment: What operating system are you running ?

Comment: @RobertPitt RHEL6 means Red Hat Enterprise Linux Version 6

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this with the [`PharData`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) class:

```
// Example: list files
$archive = new PharData('/some/file.tar.gz');
foreach($archive as $file) {
        echo "$file\n";
}
```

This even works with the `phar://` stream wrapper:

```
$list = scandir('phar:///some/file.tar.gz');
$fd = fopen('phar:///some/file.tar.gz/some/file/in/the/archive', 'r');
$contents = file_get_contents('phar:///some/file.tar.gz/some/file/in/the/archive');
```

If you don't have Phar, check the [PHP-only implementation](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Archive), or [the pecl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/phar).

Comment: seems to be a problem with certain types of tar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189687/phardata-class-fails-when-tar-contents-has-relative-paths

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to build this yourself. Use an existing class like http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar to handle that for you.

Comment: Does Archive_Tar handle compressed files? And the documentation doesn't say it can give a list of the files in a .tar file. I don't want to extract the files, I just want to list their contents.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it supports both .gz and .bz2 compression. And there is a `->listContent` method among others.

Answer (score 4):

The below code reads a file inside a **.gz** zip file

```
    <?php
    $z = gzopen('zipfile.gz','r') or die("can't open: $php_errormsg");
    $string = '';

    while ($line = gzgets($z,1024)) {
        $string .= $line;
    }

    echo $string;

    gzclose($z) or die("can't close: $php_errormsg");
    ?>
```

**Note** that you need to have the zip extension of php enabled for this code to work.

Comment: Excellent. This helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the first answer works. Or it only doesn't work for me. You could not read file content when you foreach it. I give my working code below.

```
$fh = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('phar:///dir/file.tar.gz'),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

foreach ($fh as $splFileInfo) {
    echo file_get_contents($splFileInfo->getPathname());
}
```

This works for gz, zip, tar and bz files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [zlib](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) extension

Comment: Does the zlib extension handle TAR files?

Comment: No, it only handles the gz compression/decompression. You already have better answers to handle the tar side of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

How about sticking with the original tar library (if pre-installed)?

```
echo shell_exec('tar -tf <path/to/file.tgz>');// lists the contents of a Gzipped Tarball
```

Comment: Regarding downvotes, I do believe that since you have enough reputation to vote, adding some comments about the solution that works fine on at least all major Linux systems btw is always better than a silent and anonymous downvote.