# How to read a single file inside a zip archive

Tags: php, zip, gzip, zlib

I need to read the content of a single file, "test.txt", inside of a zip file. The whole zip file is a very large file (2gb) and contains a lot of files (10,000,000), and as such extracting the whole thing is not a viable solution for me. How can I read a single file?

Comment: This question is not actually stupid. I found myself here while googling for 'extract one file from zip php'. It is strange it has votes down.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try using the [`zip://` wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php):

```
$handle = fopen('zip://test.zip#test.txt', 'r'); 
$result = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $result .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
echo $result;
```

You can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) too:

```
$result = file_get_contents('zip://test.zip#test.txt');
echo $result;
```

Comment: how to tell if the file exists? if(!@$test = file_get_contents(... ?

Comment: @user1243068: I'm not sure.  That should work.  You can use `is_file` to check if the `.zip` exists.  As for the file inside the zip, I'm not sure.

Comment: It also works with file, like $content=file('zip://test.zip#test.txt');

Comment: I have `.tar.gz` file instead of `.zip` file, how to use the `file_get_contents('zip://test.zip#test.txt');`?

Comment: @Sami: The [`phar://` wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.stream.php) seems to support this.  `file_get_contents('phar://yourfile.tar.gz/path/to/file.txt');`  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4878849

Comment: @RocketHazmat, Thanks for your response. I tried to use phar:// wrapper, but my browser loading forever and does not echo the content. I have a `.tar.gz` file with 1,000,000 `.json` files. Any idea?

Comment: @Sami: What do you mean by "crashes"?  Does it actually *crash* or does the script just stop running?  Any errors or anything?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, it loads forever :). Also, I checked the file using `tar -tf i.tar.gz` and there is no problem with the filepath.

Comment: I wonder if it's just too big of a file or something.  I'm not 100% sure what could be going on.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - have any idea how to do this with a remote https file?

Comment: @ScottPaterson: I didn't test this, but would `file_get_contents('zip://https://example.com/test.zip#test.txt');` work?  Otherwise, you'd probably need to download the file into memory (or a temp folder) first.

Answer (score 4):

Please note @Rocket-Hazmat `fopen` solution may cause an infinite loop if a zip file is protected with a password, since `fopen` will fail and `feof` fails to return true.

**You may want to change it to**

```
$handle = fopen('zip://file.zip#file.txt', 'r');
$result = '';
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $result .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo $result;
```

This solves the infinite loop issue, but if your zip file is protected with a password then you may see something like

> Warning: file_get_contents(zip://file.zip#file.txt): failed to open
> stream: operation failed

There's  a solution however

As of PHP 7.2 support for encrypted archives was added.

**So you can do it this way for both** `file_get_contents` **and** `fopen`

```
$options = [
    'zip' => [
        'password' => '1234'
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo file_get_contents('zip://file.zip#file.txt', false, $context);
```

**A better solution however to check if a file exists or not before reading it without worrying about encrypted archives is using** [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('file.zip') !== TRUE) {
    exit('failed');
}
if ($zip->locateName('file.txt') !== false) {
    echo 'File exists';
} else {
    echo 'File does not exist';
}
```

This will work (no need to know the password)

> Note: To locate a folder using `locateName` method you need to pass it like `folder/` with a
> forward slash at the end.