# Open content.xml in a odt-file directly via php

Tags: php, odt

Is it possible to open a xml-file in a odt-container (which is a zip-container) directly via php?
By now I extract the odt-container manually to get the content.xml file out of it. Would be much easier if my php-script could process the odt-file directly.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open("content.xml", 'UTF-8')) die("Failed to open 'content.xml'");
while ($reader->read()){ 
    // Do further processing
}
```

**Update:**
`$reader->open('zip://'.$odt_file.'#content.xml')`

Comment: First unzip the file http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php and than read the XML?

Comment: Do I really have to unzip it and delete the extracted file after processing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420112/how-to-read-a-single-file-inside-a-zip-archive May answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly.