# Reading files from ZIP without extracting to disk

Tags: php, zip

Is it possible to open a ZIP file on a server, read a file from its content and display it / send it to a client directly without extracting it to disk first ? I am talking about `pdf's` and `images`. Haven't found any hints in the php sites.

Comment: What platform are you trying to develop in?

Comment: sorry I forgot - Linux , Apache, PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a single file inside a zip archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420112/how-to-read-a-single-file-inside-a-zip-archive)

Answer (score 1):

Well,there is a PHP [Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). 
If you use the extractTo method, you would be able to extract a single file, checkout the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php).

From the documentation, extracting two files:-

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test_im.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', array('pear_item.gif', 'testfromfile.php'));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

You would need to provide an array of path inside the zip.

Comment: not quite right - if you only want a single file then just the filename and/or path not an array.  You supply an array if you are extracting multiple files I believe. So, $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', 'pear_item.gif'); if you only want pear_item.gif.