# How to read excel files from zip using PHPExcel_IOFactory in yii2?

Tags: php, excel, yii2, zip

I'm able to read excel files from a folder using PHPExcel_IOFactory, but I'm not able to open and read Excel files from Zip.

Below is the code snippet

```
$inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("data\file.zip\\"."excel1.xlsx");
```

Getting below error

> Exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open
>   data\file.zip\excel1.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.'

Comment: You need to unzip excel first. [ZipArchive::open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php)

Comment: I have used like below $zip = new \ZipArchive(); if($zip->open('data\file.zip') == TrUE){ //here my code to read $inputFileType }.  Still getting Exception

Comment: [How to open and read from zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420112/how-to-read-a-single-file-inside-a-zip-archive)

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it will not work for me. In my case, PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify() must idenfy the files from zip. Because I have to read each sheet from excel file.

Comment: I understand that, But first you have to get file from zip file in order to read it. Add what you tried so far.