# How to read a single file inside a remote zip archive (url with zip)

Tags: php, zip, fopen, file-get-contents

I would like to read zip file with TXT file inside, but my zip exists on different url, not on the local machine.
I tried both ways without success.

1. $result = file_get_contents('zip://http://www.abcde.com/12345.zip#1234.txt');
   or
2. $fp = fopen('zip://http://www.abcde.com/12345.zip#1234.txt', 'r');
   Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a single file inside a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420112/how-to-read-a-single-file-inside-a-zip-archive)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to copy the zip from remote to local and then it should work better.