# how to uncompress a folder with with extension gzip

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with a folder with an extension .gz in the client side which contains xml files in it. I have to download the folder into local directory then i need to extract the folder.

I was able to download the .gz folder into local, but I'm unable to extract the folder.

I tried using the

```
ZipArchive::extractto($targetfolder);
```

But it is not accepting the .gz.

When i search through stack overflow i found only answers for .gz files not for .gz folders.

Comment: What is it a `gz` folder? `gz` is a file format. Is it just a folder that was named `something.gz`?

Comment: did you try right clicking on it and clicking "extract"?

Comment: Yes it is named with the file.xml.gz

Comment: when i extracted the folder by right clicking on it a file with the name file.xml extracted into the folder file.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP's built-in [gzfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzfile.php) function.

This will uncompress the file in 4kB chunks:

```
function uncompress($srcName, $dstName) {
    $sfp = gzopen($srcName, "rb");
    $fp = fopen($dstName, "w");

    while ($string = gzread($sfp, 4096)) {
        fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
    }
    gzclose($sfp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Hi -- I'm just curious if what I suggested above worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) doesn't say anything about being able to open `gz` format files (`zip` and `gz` are *not* the same). You may need to use [Zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) to decompress your `gz` file, and if it's a `tar.gz` or `tgz` file, you'll also need something to untar the file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781101/how-to-extract-a-tar-gz-archive-in-php-without-system) and [this newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php) discuss how to extract a `tar.gz` file in PHP.