# Get contents from gzipped file

Tags: php, gzip, mailchimp

I am trying to get the contents from a gzipped file that is returned to me after using Mailchimp API doing a batch operation request. I expect to get only a JSON string as response, but also receive a bunch of numbers and random (?) strings.

This is what I do.

```
$gz = gzopen($response->response_body_url, "r");
$contents = trim(gzread($gz, 10000));
print_r($contents); //see output below
gzclose($gz);
```

This is what is returned to me.

> 0000777000000000000000000000000012705141572007721 5ustar
>   rootroot./05fa27ceab.json0000666000000000000000000000121212705141572012327
>   0ustar
>   rootroot[**{"status_code":400,"operation_id":null,"response":"{\"type\":\"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/\",\"title\":\"Member
>   Exists\",\"status\":400,\"detail\":\"xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xx is
>   already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list
>   members.\",\"instance\":\"\"}"},{"status_code":400,"operation_id":null,"response":"{\"type\":\"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/\",\"title\":\"Member
>   Exists\",\"status\":400,\"detail\":\"xxxx2.xxxx2@xxxx2.xx is
>   already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list
>   members.\",\"instance\":\"\"}"}**]

What am I missing here? Why won't it work?

Comment: is it really a gzipped file or is it merely the http response being deflated?

Comment: Well, this is actually pretty much all I do. The `$response->response_body_url` contains the URL to where the zip is located. Downloading and opening it from my browser works fine. I tried a bunch of different approaches. This one seems to be the closest as the actual JSON string is in there. Unfortunately I am not able to tell you if it's deflated or not...?

Comment: Can you post a link to the file if possible?

Comment: Trust me, I would if I could. But it contains some info I'm not sure I'm supposed to share here... :/ Sorry to be so unhelpful. I can't seem to find anything about anyone having a similar problem either :/

Comment: Would a somewhat edited content of the downloaded file do?

Comment: probably not, since the problem appears to be with the gzip decoding.

Comment: Can you share sample gzipped content for inspect the issue? I guess you can download file_put_contents(somewhere,$response->response_body_url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be dealing with a `.tar.gz` file instead of just gzip. The easiest way to do that is either with the `PharData` extension or by just saving it to disk and using a shell tool to unzip.

[Here's an answer to a question on how to deal with .tar.gz files in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php)