# How to validate a .tar.gz archive in PHP?

Tags: php

The user uploads a `.tar.gz` archive and I need to validate if the archive contains a certain file (I just need to check the filename, nothing else).

I know I can open the file using `\PharData` however it seems that it loads the entire archive into memory. Since the archive is a backup and can easily be bigger than memory_limit, I can't use this.

How can I do the validation without loading the whole file to memory? In case it is impossible to do in PHP (as I suspect), how can I do it in bash? Again without loading the entire file to memory at once and also without actually unpacking the archive.

Comment: Have you tried it via the phar:// stream wrapper?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you just can use bash command for that:

`tar -t - show list of files`

[image]